# True or False - Convergence

Tags: calculus

can someone give me some hints about this question - True or False:

For all $0<a<1$:

> $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a}{a^2+n^2}<\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 5):

Draw the first quadrant part of the curve $y=\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}$. Argue that our sum is less than
$$\frac{a}{a^2+1^2}+\int_1^\infty \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}\,dx.$$

For the integral, make the change of variable $x=at$. The integral is equal to
$$\int_{1/a}^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt.$$
This is less than the integral from $1$ to $\infty$, which is $\pi/4$.

To finish, it is enough to show that $\frac{a}{a^2+1}\lt 1/2$. This is can be done, for example, by using standard calculus tools.

There are nicer ways. For example, the inequality is equivalent to $2a\lt a^2+1$, or equivalently $(1-a)^2 \gt 0$.

Comment: Hey! thank you for your answer. why our sum is less than $\frac{a}{a^2+1^2}+\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx$ ?

Comment: I separated  out the first term. The rest is $\sum_2^{\infty} \frac{a}{a^2+n^2}$. Draw the curve mentioned in the answer. Draw the rectangle base $[1,2]$, height $\frac{a}{a^2+2^2}$. Draw the rectangle with base $[2,3]$ height  $\frac{a}{a^2+3^2}$, and so on forever.  The sum of the areas of the rectangles is $\sum_2^\infty \frac{a}{a^2+n^2}$. The union of these rectangles is contained in the region below $y=\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}$, above the $x$-axis, from $1$ to $\infty$.  So the sum $\sum_2^\infty$ is less than $\int_1^\infty \frac{a}{a^2+x^2}\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

By considering the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the $\sinh$ function we have:
$$ f(a)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a}{a^2+n^2}=\frac{-1+\pi a\coth(\pi a)}{2a}\tag{1} $$
and the RHS is an increasing function over $[0,1]$, hence:
$$\forall a\in[0,1],\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a}{a^2+n^2}\leq\frac{-1+\pi\coth\pi}{2}=1.076674\ldots\tag{2}$$
and the given inequality is true.